# Add DropDownChoice to a DropDownChoice

Tags: wicket, submenu, dropdownchoice

Is it possible in the Apache Wicket Framework to add a DropDownChoice to another DropDownChoice? 
For example:

- Main-Dropdown

  - First-Subdropdown
  - Second-Subdropdown

I have to categorize my values, that's why I have to do that. Otherwise its not userfriendly anymore.

I'm using Wicket 1.4.17.

Comment: It's not possible to add a ddc to another ddc but you can create a panel with 3 ddc's and by adding OnChangeAjaxBehaviors to each update the ddc's accordingly.

Comment: Is it also not possible to add a submenu? Like this?:
- Dropdown
 - Sub --> - Sub1
           - Sub2

?

Comment: I dont understand. Is this an option for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup ?